# How to get a particular pattern from a Column

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, pattern-matching

**My current situation:**

```sql
    WITH q AS (
    SELECT 'ISSUE TO LANDING GEAR
    REQ# 1176516
    WO108591' AS sentence FROM DUAL
    )
    select substr(x,0,7) from(
    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(sentence, '.*\w\#\s', '', 1, 0, 'n') as x FROM q);`
```

> Output ***1176516*** which is partially correct

However, below is my testing code. where I m stuck

**Here is my test case code:**

```sql
    WITH q AS (SELECT 'ISSUE TO LANDING GEARREQ# 1176516
    WO108591 REQUEST 54 BY ARREQ 2 AND PARKING# 345 INTO SEQ' AS sentence
   FROM DUAL)
   SELECT regexp_substr(sentence, '\w\d[.](\D|\d+[^.])*$') FROM q;`
```

**Expected Output:**

> REQ# 1176516

I need to find any pattern like "REQ#" or "REQ #" or "  REQ#" or "  REQ #" and get the next 7 numbers associated next to it.

**Test Scenarios:**

" WHAT COULD BE THE REQ # 2145673"

" HOW MANY REQ# 1234673 COULD BE THERE"

" REQ# 2398723 OR THE SECOND REQ#"

"GEARREQ#1232124"

"REQ # 1234567, REQ# 1234886" in this case the first occurrence that is 1234567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
WITH q AS (
      SELECT 'ISSUE TO LANDING GEARREQ# 1176516
WO108591 REQUEST 54 BY ARREQ 2 AND PARKING# 345 INTO SEQ' AS sentence
      FROM DUAL
     )
SELECT substr(regexp_substr(sentence, 'REQ ?# ?\d{7}'), -7)
FROM q;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, What happens in this situation: 'ISSUE TO LANDING GEARREQ# 637542 WB19847 1. ECD = 8/1/1600. 7/20/16 MH' nothing shows up

Comment: @StackOne . . . This question explicitly asks about *7* digits ("I need to find any pattern like "REQ#" or "REQ #" or " REQ#" or " REQ #" and get the next 7 numbers associated next to it.").  If you have a different question, then ask as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In your followup responses to the OP, you inquired about the possibility
of the key number being a different length than seven. In addition to 
a solution to matching exactly seven digits after `REQ #`,  here are some
variations on this theme to illustrate changing specifications on 
the length of the number after the keyword.

```
with q as ( 
        select 'WHAT COULD BE THE REQ # 2145673' as sentence from dual union all
        select 'HOW MANY REQ# 1234673 COULD BE THERE' as sentence from dual union all 
        select 'REQ# 2398723 OR THE SECOND REQ#' as sentence from dual union all 
        select 'GEARREQ#1232124' as sentence from dual union all 
        select 'REQ # 1234567, REQ# 1234886'  as sentence from dual union all
        select 'REQ # 1, REQ# 1234886'  as sentence from dual union all
        select 'REQ # 123, REQ# 1234886'  as sentence from dual union all
        select 'REQ # 123456789, REQ# 1234886'  as sentence from dual union all
        select 'REQ # 1234567890, REQ# 1234886'  as sentence from dual
        )
select sentence,
       -- Locating just the key characters, allows you to accomodate 
       -- variable length numbers following the key characters.
       regexp_substr(sentence,'REQ *# *',1)                  as keyword_find,
       regexp_substr(sentence,'REQ *# *[[:digit:]]+',1)      as keyword_then_any_digits,
       regexp_substr(sentence,'REQ *# *[[:digit:]]{7}',1)    as kw_match_exatly_seven,
       regexp_substr(sentence,'REQ *# *[[:digit:]]{1,7}',1)  as kw_match_1_to_7_digits,
       regexp_substr(sentence,'REQ *# *[[:digit:]]{3,10}',1) as kw_match_3_to_10_digits,
-- Some additional formatting will remove excess spaces and render output to specs.
--- First regexp_substr selects the relevant text to format.
--  Second regexp_substr grabs the number portion of relevant text.
--  Then just append REQ# to front of that number.
     'REQ# ' || regexp_substr(regexp_substr(sentence,'REQ *# *[[:digit:]]{7}',1),'[[:digit:]]+') as format_exactly_7
from q;
```